# Why is HTML 5 validation triggering when I run Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a button that triggers the below jquery function.  Currently the function works and hides/shows the form element as desired.  However it is tripping the html 5 validation (which I want on submit).  Is there a reason it is triggering and a way I can prevent this?  I experimented with having a return at the end of the function but no luck.  Also neither form is required as part of the validation.  I keep getting a pop up telling me previous items are required when I hide/show the form elements..

```html
<button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-success" onclick ="hideFormField ()">Hide</button>
```

```js
function hideFormField (){
    if(!$("#trail").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#trail").show();
        $("#blazers").hide();
    }else{
        $("#trail").hide();
        $("#blazers").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and clear on the question? you want to turn off the default HTML5 validation or something else?

Comment: `<button type="button" ...>`. Button elements without a `type` are submit buttons by default and will act accordingly within a `<form>`.

Comment: Have you validated your page as valid HTML5 code to begin with?   (https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)  This will step through and point out any HTML5 errors as you go that may exist prior to even firing the click event which may just be the action that occurs that makes visible the issue.

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your question.  [tag:jquery-validate] is only used for that specific plugin, and [tag:html-validation] is only used regarding validation of HTML to W3 standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-success" onclick ="hideFormField ();return false;">Hide</button>
```

Comment: I tried this one first and it worked.  I also added the type as button.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-success" onclick="hideFormField();event.preventDefault();">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Lonowski was correct in his comment. Buttons are submit-type by default so you need to explicitly define a button with `type="button"` attribute if you don't want any additional effects when the button is clicked.

A small example that illustrate the activation of HTML5 form validation through default button behavior is in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zk3jr9vn/

Answer (score 0):

by default button is submit type so add Type to button
like

```
<button type="button" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-success" onclick ="hideFormField ()">Hide</button>
```